# Tahoma font family not work in mobile device

Tags: html, css

Tahoma and verdana font not work in mobile or tablet

My code is :

```
* {
font-family:tahoma,verdana !important;
}
```

But not work in mobile devices

Comment: are they native to mobile?

Comment: native to mobile ? what is this ?

Comment: As in, are those 2 fonts already installed on mobile devices? If they aren't, they won't load

Comment: No, this font not in android , but can i load this font ?

Comment: The observation is correct. What is the question?

Comment: The way you are defining the font requires it to be installed on the device. IF you are using a font that is not in the system then you need to call them in using @font-face with the relevant files

Comment: Thank you , i have use @font-face

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the font file you want, and upload it to fontsquirrel.com.

Then take out the following fonts from the package and add the following into your CSS file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Tahoma';
src: url('path/to/Tahoma.eot');
src: url('path/to/Tahoma.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('path/to/Tahoma.woff') format('woff'),
     url('path/to/Tahoma.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('path/to/Tahoma.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

You can then use the font in your css file by using:

```
font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Not in this case, Tahoma is a font included on every computer. It's widely available. It's even a web-safe font http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: It's a websafe font in the way that it's installed on computers. That doesn't mean it's not copyrighted

Comment: Thx , can you give me tahoma.eot and woff and ttf and svg fonts ?

Comment: You'll need to find the font on your computer. Obviously make sure its license enables you to use it elsewhere on the web. My suggestion would be to find a royalty free font, and use that. Or Google Fonts.

Comment: “© 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.” http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1951 (or look at the font information in the font file)

Comment: You are allowed to use Tahoma as a webfont. It doesn't say in the license info that you're not allowed to use it. Everything is copyrighted. Being able to use it is something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Most android phones only have a few fonts available by default.

Comment: Can you help for list of this fonts ?

Comment: I guess the problem with android is that this is brand specific. I have heard that some android devices have droid-serif and droid sans by default.

Answer (score 1):

Tahoma is not available on mobile.

You can upload the font to your site and load it with css. See also Google Fonts ;)

Edit : be careful of copyright